# How to resize a single View in my Layout when the Keyboard appears?

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, resize, android-softkeyboard

I have built a search function for my app and i display the results in a listview that sits ontop of the rest of the layout.
the layout is optimized for honeycomb tablets.
everything works fine except that i do not want the keyboard to overlap my listview. i want to resize it in hight so it fits in the remaining space.
does anybody have an idea?

i know one can set the android:windowSoftInputMode parameter in the manifest but that is not working for me because it affects the whole activity. i only want to resize one single view.

Comment: Not really sure if this still works in HC: you could override your Activity's onConfigurationChanged() to be notified when the keyboard pops up. Don't fortget to add to you Manifest android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, yes you want to use the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". Just set everything to android:layout_height="wrap_content" except for the ListView, which you set to android:layout_height="match_parent"; that should keep everything the same other than the ListView, which will be resized to fit the remaining space.